# How to draw an image in TabPage above nested Buttons

Tags: c#, forms, draw

How to draw image on tabPage overlapping buttons

Black circles(DrawImage on tabPage8_Paint) should be **above** the buttons:

http://rghost.ru/6sVBl8mkh/image.png

It must be so: 
http://rghost.ru/6BgDM77pq/image.png

My code

```
public SibModem() {

    InitializeComponent();

    tabPage8.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(tabPage8_Paint);
    gettime();

    this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(this.SibModem_Resize);
}

protected void tabPage8_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {

    GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
    base.OnPaint(e);

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawImage(bg, 0, 0);

    Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(offsetant, 0, w, h);
    g.DrawImage(anten, x, y, srcRect, units);

    Rectangle ussdwaitRect = new Rectangle(offsetussd, 0, 64, 64);
    g.DrawImage(ussdwait, usx, usy, ussdwaitRect, units);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't draw **above** nested controls, so you need to draw parts of the image **onto** those Buttons.

So combine drawing **onto the tabpage** and drawing **onto the buttons** you need to adorn!

Here is a simple example using only one image:

[image]

A few class level variables:

```
Point iLoc = Point.Empty;
Image img = null;
List<Button> overlaidButtons = new List<Button>();
```

Prepare the image, its position and a list of possibly overlaid buttons:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string imgN = @"d:\scrape\gears\gear_12x4hand.png";
    img = Image.FromFile(imgN);
    iLoc = new Point(100, 100);
    overlaidButtons.AddRange(new []{button10,button11,button12,button13 });
    // each button calls the same paint event
    foreach (Button btn in overlaidButtons) btn.Paint += btn_Paint;
}
```

The common `Paint` event. We calculate the relative position of the image..

```
void btn_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(iLoc.X - btn.Left, iLoc.Y - btn.Top));
}
```

Note that if the `Buttons` are nested deeper you need to adapt the calculation to include all levels of nesting!

The `TabPage Paint` event:

```
private void tabPage5_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, iLoc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try BringToFront method, it brings the control to the front of the z-order.

See this reference on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: as it is applied to - Image ussdwait =
        global::SibModem.Properties.Resources.waitpl;  Rectangle        ussdwaitRect = new Rectangle(offsetussd, 0, 64, 64);
 g.DrawImage(ussdwait, usx, usy, ussdwaitRect, units);

Comment: Image Is not Control  can not do so `ussdwait.BringToFront();` or  `g.BringToFront();`   `button4.SendToBack();` - still overlapping images **ussdwait** (black circles)