# DrawLine() on top of labels

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, label

I am attempting to use DrawLine() on a label, however it appears that the label is always positioned on top of the drawn line. I have tried a number of things, like Bring to Front, Send to Bottom, use label1.show() after I drawn the line. None of which worked. The attached image illustrates the issue I am having. Any input on how to put the line on top will be appreciated.

[image: DrawLine() on top of a label]

Comment: Draw the text, too.

Comment: It is next to impossible and really doesn't make much sense. The workaround would be to draw line segment in the Labels' Paint events. [Possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195719/how-to-draw-an-image-in-tabpage-above-nested-buttons/34197510#34197510) but also terribly complicated compared to : Drawing the  the Label texts with TextRenderer.DrawString

Comment: Agree with taw... inherited control approach for that

Comment: Tagging this as computer-science is a bit over the top - Also: Make that TexRenderer.DrawText

Comment: It is not possible, really and: It would not be any more efficient performancewise: the system must draw the lables as well and at the same cost as you draw the texts..

Comment: I typed CS (C# file format), but StackOverflow changed it to computer-science :P Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

try this code, first on load all labels make to invisible, then on paint form event, draw the text before draw the line.

```
private void Form1_Paint ( object sender , PaintEventArgs e ) {     

            foreach (var ctl in this.Controls ) {
                if(ctl.GetType () == typeof ( Label ) ) {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString ( ( ( Label ) ctl ).Text , ( ( Label ) ctl ).Font , new SolidBrush ( ( ( Label ) ctl ).ForeColor ) , ( ( Label ) ctl ).Location  );
                }
            }


            using ( var pen = new Pen ( Color.Blue , 10 ) ) {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine ( pen , 0 , 0 , 200 , 100 );
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load ( object sender , EventArgs e ) {
            foreach ( var ctl in this.Controls ) {
                if ( ctl.GetType ( ) == typeof ( Label ) ) {
                    ( ( Label ) ctl ).Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

the result:
[image]